# Initialization of an array of pointers with predefined pointers to strings?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How to initialize an array of pointers with predefined pointers to strings . Please can some one Help me with it and explain to me the logic behind it . thank you in advance I appreciate your help.

```
char *str1 = NULL, *str2 = NULL, *str3 = NULL ;
char *array[n]={str1, str2, str3};
int n=3;
printf("\n\t\t\t *** Zeile als Zeichenkette einlesen *** \n");
for(int i=0;i<n ;i++) {
    printf("Die eingelesene Zeichenkette ist : %s \n", array[i] [0]=zeichenketteEinlesen());
    printf("test %s \n",str1);
    free(str1);
}
```

this is my whole Program

```
char* zeichenketteEinlesen(void){
    int i=0;
    char c ;
    char *Z_Kette = NULL ;
    Z_Kette = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)) ;
    if(NULL == Z_Kette) {
        printf("Kein virtueller RAM mehr verfuegbar ...\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Geben Sie Die Zeichenkette ein bitte ! :");
    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' ){
         Z_Kette=(char*)realloc(Z_Kette, (i+2)*sizeof(char));
            if(NULL == Z_Kette) {
                printf("Kein virtueller RAM mehr verfuegbar ...\n");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            Z_Kette [i++] = (char)c ;
    }
    Z_Kette[i] = '\0' ;
    return Z_Kette ;
}
int main()
{
    char *str1 = NULL, *str2 = NULL, *str3 = NULL ;
    char *array[n]={str1, str2, str3};
    int n=3;
    printf("\n\t\t\t *** Zeile als Zeichenkette einlesen *** \n");
    for(int i=0;i<n ;i++) {
        printf("Die eingelesene Zeichenkette ist : %s \n", array[i][0]=zeichenketteEinlesen());
        printf("test %s \n",str1);
        free(str1);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do exactly what you're asking in the first two lines. But you use `n` before it is declared -- and it doesn't make any sense to make this a variable length array if you have a compile time constant number of elements anyways, so just leave out `n` in the declaration.

Comment: thak you for replaying

Comment: i've tried it . char *array[3]={str1, str2, str3};  but without  success

Comment: Hint: you need a couple of 'const'.

Comment: what do you mean by "without success"? Of course, your variables `strX` are a bit pointless, but of course this works.

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indention. And it isn't clear what exactly you don't understand here.

Comment: @MartinJames no `const`s needed for these declarations...

Comment: @FelixPalmen Not needed to sate the C standard, but needed to achieve decent code quality.

Comment: @Lundin of course, but without stating that, it's misleading as a comment :)

Comment: i want to access  the diefferent pointers in the array using the ( for ) loop   and dereference the pointers in order to display the strings they point to . is the initialisation of the array of pointers ok ?? `char *str1 = NULL, *str2 = NULL, *str3 = NULL ;
    char  *(*array)[3]={str1, str2, str3};`

Comment: I don't like:  char *array[n]={str1, str2, str3};

Comment: char *array[3];

Comment: how can i then initialize the array then ??

Comment: array[0] = str1; array[1] = str2; array[2] = str3;  // actually, this is wrong

Comment: You don't need to initialize the array.  It is already an array of char pointers.  Just assign to the array as you would to str1, str2, str3.

Comment: If you want to access the pointers using str1, it would make more sense to:   str1 = array[0];

Comment: OT: write English code - that is, names of variables and functions should be English

Comment: Sorry i've already written the code in the German Language . thank you all for the answers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *str1 = NULL, *str2 = NULL, *str3 = NULL ;
char *array[n]={str1, str2, str3};
int n=3;
```

1. You should initialize an array with a constant, e.g., 3, not a variable.
2. defining array in this way is ok in syntax, though it is not logically correct.

Below is my code (I refactor the format for a better look):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* zeichenketteEinlesen(void){
    int i=0;
    char c ;
    char *Z_Kette = NULL ;
    Z_Kette = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)) ;
    if(NULL == Z_Kette) {
        printf("Kein virtueller RAM mehr verfuegbar ...\n");
        // incompatible return type
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Geben Sie Die Zeichenkette ein bitte ! :");
    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' ){
        Z_Kette=(char*)realloc(Z_Kette, (i+2)*sizeof(char));
        if(NULL == Z_Kette) {
            printf("Kein virtueller RAM mehr verfuegbar ...\n");
            // incompatible return type too
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        Z_Kette [i++] = (char)c ;
    }
    Z_Kette[i] = '\0' ;
    return Z_Kette ;
}

int main() {
    char *str1 = NULL, *str2 = NULL, *str3 = NULL ;
    // logic error, what you want is to change strx, while in your way it changes array elements.
    char **array[3]={&str1, &str2, &str3};
    int n=3;
    printf("\n\t\t\t *** Zeile als Zeichenkette einlesen *** \n");
    for(int i=0;i<n ;i++){
        // you should not use array[i][0], since array[i] is not an array
        printf("Die eingelesene Zeichenkette ist : %s \n", *(array[i])=zeichenketteEinlesen());
        // here, you should use / free an appropriate pointer in every loop cycle.
        // (but below is not a good way to do this, you can improve it)
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("test %s \n",str1);
            free(str1);
        } else if (i == 1) {
            printf("test %s \n",str2);
            free(str2);
        } else {
            printf("test %s \n",str3);
            free(str3);
        }
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: array[i][0]=zeichenketteEinlesen()); //This is a big problem.

Comment: @Jiminion yeah, you are right. There are several problems in his code. So I think he might be a new in C.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be: (array[i])=zeichenketteEinlesen()) ;  ?

Comment: Thank you . I've been trying to figure it out for 2 days . This helped me a lot thank you for the explanation too .

Comment: @Jiminion As he want to assign values to str1 / str2 / ..., not to the elements of the array. So `array` must be declared to `char **` instead of `char *`.

Comment: is it possible to free the Pointers str1, str2, and str3 . in the same (for) loop ?? i mean without the " if else " . would this be a solution:  ` free(*(array[i]));`  ??

Comment: @Yass Yes, absolutely right. Actually you can replace strx with `*(array[i])` anywhere, as they 2 are completely same.

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: @Yass You are welcome :)

Comment: terry.qiao,  I am glad you were able to help Yass out.